# New line in field with jOpenDocument in ODT document

Tags: java, odt, opendocument, jopendocument

I'm trying to fill out a template from java with jOpenDocument library.

I want to start a new line in a field.
The normal new line sign (\n) does not work.

When I do this manually in a document and look in the xml file (content.xml), I see why this does not work. For every new line in the field, there is a separate paragraph.

So maybe there is a way to combine multiple paragraphs in one object and then call setField() with the multiple paragraphs object. But until now I haven't found any solution.

Code Example:

```
EngineTemplate template = new RhinoTemplate(templateFile);
template.setField("nameField", "this is the content\nI wish to be multilined");
```

Comment: It would help if you could submit a snippet of your code that you're using to do this.

Comment: I've added a codesnipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically `\n` are skipped by default, but you can change it by starting your field name in your template with `%enc:`.

Here is explanation from `org.jopendocument.dom.template.engine.Processor` class documentation:

> Generates the final document content from the preprocessed template content. 
>   The behaviour of the substitution of fields can be controlled with prefixes:
>
> **AS_STR**
>   the following expression will be substitued as a String. For an XML element its tree will be outputed.
>
> **ENCODE**
>   the following expression will be converted to a String with toString() and then encoded using org.jopendocument.dom.OOXML.encodeWS(java.lang.String).
>
> **OO_XML**
>   the following expression will be converted to a String with toString() and then parsed as OO XML.
>
> If none of these is specified, an XML element will be treated as OO XML to be grafted (only its children), else the value will simply be set as text of the field.

And `ENCODE` field is declared:

```
public static final String ENCODE = "%enc:";
```

Comment: Could you give a little example. I tried setField("nameField", Processor.ENCODE + "multlined\ncontent");, but this didn't worked. The content of the field was then: %enc:multilined content.

Comment: I've edited answer for clarification, the prefix is for the name in template not the usage in java. So you should name your field in template `%enc:nameField` and in java use `setField("nameField","multlined\ncontent");`